# React Todo List App

Tags: react.js, jsx, to-do-list

I have made a small app in React that fulfils the following user stories:

```
GIVEN I add an item using the form 
THEN I see the text appear in the list below

GIVEN I see items in the list
AND I click the close button next to a list item
THEN the list item disappears from the page

GIVEN I refresh the page at any point
THEN I see the list that I saw on the page before I refreshed
```

Here is my code:

```
const TodoInput = props => {
    return (
        <form>
            <div>Enter a todo</div>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={props.onHandleChangeInputVal}
                value={props.inputVal}
            />
            <button
                type="submit"
                onClick={props.onHandleAddTodo}
            >
                Add to the list
            </button>
        </form>
    )
};

class TodosList extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            inputVal: '',
            todos: []
        };

        this.onHandleChangeInputVal = this.onHandleChangeInputVal.bind(this);
        this.onHandleAddTodo = this.onHandleAddTodo.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const todosFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localStorageTodos'));

        this.setState({
            todos: todosFromLocalStorage || []
        })
    }

    getTodos() {
        const todos = this.state.todos;

        return todos.map((todo, index) => {
            return (
                <li
                    key={index}
                >
                    {todo}
                    <button onClick={event => this.onHandleDeleteTodo(event, index)}>&times;</button>
                </li>
            )
        })
    }

    onHandleChangeInputVal(e) {
        const newInputVal = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            inputVal: newInputVal
        })
    }

    onHandleAddTodo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();

        if (this.state.inputVal) {
            todosCopy.push(this.state.inputVal);
        }

        this.setState({
            todos: todosCopy,
            inputVal: ''
        }, () => {
            this.updateLocalStorageWithState();
        });

    }

    onHandleDeleteTodo(event, indexOfItemToRemove) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();

        todosCopy.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);

        this.setState({
            todos: todosCopy
        }, () => {
            this.updateLocalStorageWithState();
        });

    }

    updateLocalStorageWithState() {
        localStorage.setItem('localStorageTodos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos));
    }

    render() {
        const todos = this.getTodos();

        return (
            <div>
                <TodoInput
                    onHandleChangeInputVal={this.onHandleChangeInputVal}
                    onHandleAddTodo={this.onHandleAddTodo}
                    inputVal={this.state.inputVal}
                />
                <ul>{todos}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodosList />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/RoKBLr?editors=0010

Please can you review for any improvements to how I have structured and written my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, I like your code. Especially, since you have the `TodoInput` as a separate stateless component. IMHO, there is still some room for improvement, though:

- You shouldn't use `setState` in `componentDidMount` since this will [trigger a re-rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Since `localStorage.getItem` is synchronous anyway, you can initialise the state in the constructor and remove `componentDidMount` completely.
- If you change the signature of `onHandleDeleteTodo`, you don't need to reference `event` in `getTodos`:

```js
getTodos() {
  // ...
  <button onClick={this.onHandleDeleteTodo(index)}
  // ...
}

onHandleDeleteTodo(indexOfItemToRemove) {
  return (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();

    todosCopy.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);

    this.setState({
        todos: todosCopy
    }, () => {
        this.updateLocalStorageWithState();
    });
  }
}
```

- I would probably use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `Array.slice` and `Array.push` (in `onHandleAddTodo`)
- You don't need the extra arrow function in `onHandleAddTodo`:

```js
this.setState({
  todos: todosCopy
}, () => {
  this.updateLocalStorageWithState();
});
```

is equivalent to

```
this.setState({
  todos: todosCopy
}, this.updateLocalStorageWithState);
```

- The prefix `onHandle` doesn't sound right to me. I would probably just use `on` for the naming of the prop (i.e. `props.onChangeInputVal` in `TodoInput`) and `handle` for the actual implementation that will be passed down (i.e. `handleChangeInputVal` in `TodosList`. Furthermore, I would rename the prop `inputVal` to `value` since that is the naming convention used for [form elements in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).